# const alias for a non-const object

Tags: c, gcc, constants, language-lawyer

Is the following valid "GNU C"?

```
int foo;
const int bar __attribute__((__alias__("foo")));
```

In other words, can I have a `const`-qualified alias for an object that's mutable? The motivation would be to avoid spurious reloads of an object that's only written at program initialization time, in cases where compiler barriers or memory barriers would otherwise cause the compiler to reload.

GCC does not issue any warning or error for the above, but C explicitly forbids (in the sense that the behavior is undefined) mis-declaring an `extern` object `const` when the actual definition is not `const`, presumably because doing so could cause valid transformations (omitting repeated loads) to change the behavior of the program, and using the alias seems like a way to cheat and get around the formal UB while allowing (and in my case, requesting) the exact same dangerous transformations.

Is there any official word on whether GCC supports such usage?

Comment: The lack of any warning is simply because GCC does not really use the alias attribute in a meaningful way during compilation, IIRC, it simply ends up forwarding it to the assembler and from there to the linker. It's not an indication of whether your code is valid. A suggestion: see how a C++ `const` object with dynamic initialisation is represented by G++, and emulate that?